# Problem with having actionSheet open a new view (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I am trying to write a basic apps using different views. On the main screen there is a button which should open another view. the view is in another swift file called ThoughtsView.swift with the struct ThoughtsView().

Code of my main view:

```
struct NewThoughtView: View {

    @State var thought = ""
    @State var modalIsPresented = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                Spacer()

                TextField("Type your thought...", text: $thought)

                Spacer()

                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                    Text("Ok")
                }

                Spacer()
                Spacer()


                // Thought Library Button

                Button(action: {self.modalIsPresented = true}) {
                    Text("Review your thoughts")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Skillful"))

        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented) {

            ThoughtsView(thoughtStore: ThoughtStore())
        }

    }
}

struct NewThoughtView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewThoughtView()
    }
}
```

It throws following error:

**Cannot convert value of type 'ThoughtsView()' to closure result type 'ActionSheet'**

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YSju.png)

This is the swift file containing the ThoughtsView, which I want to be in the new actionsheet:

```
struct ThoughtsView: View {

    var thoughtStore: ThoughtStore


    var body: some View {



        List(thoughtStore.thoughts, id: \.id) {thought in
            Text(thought.thoughtName)
        }
    }
}

struct ThoughtsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ThoughtsView( thoughtStore: ThoughtStore() )
    }
}
```

In case the error is here, code of the sceneDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo _: UISceneSession, options _: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).



        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

            // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
                   let contentView = NewThoughtView()

            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: hello, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I just change in your code, on button tap open your view. I assume you are trying to do that.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var thought = ""
@State var modalIsPresented = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TextField("Type your thought...", text: $thought)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text("Ok")
            }
            Spacer()
            Spacer()

            // Thought Library Button

            Button(action: {self.modalIsPresented = true}) {
                Text("Review your thoughts")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented, content: {
                 ThoughtsView(thoughtStore: ThoughtStore())
            })
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Skillful"))
    }
    /*.actionSheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented) {

        ThoughtsView()
    }*/
}
```

}